# Se ha dado este error a la hora de darle salida -1.#IND00? Haciendo la formula cuadratica

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    
    float xpositivo=0, xnegativo=0;
    float b=0, a=0, c=0;
    
    printf("Dgite el valor de A:\t");
    scanf("%f",&a);
    printf("Dgite el valor de B:\t");
    scanf("%f",&b);
    printf("Dgite el valor de C:\t");
    scanf("%f",&c);
    
    //Desarrollo de la formula
    
    xpositivo = (-b+sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);
    xnegativo = (-b-sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);
    
    printf("\n___________________________________");
    printf("\nEl resultado positivo es: %f\n\n",xpositivo);
    printf("El resultado negativo es: %f",xnegativo);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Les dejo mi código, estoy haciendo la formula cuadrática y al final, cuando quiero mostrar los resultados, me da como salida **-1.#IND00**

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias describir en que punto te da ese error?

Comment: Eso parece C, no C++.

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y no veo ningún problema. 
Solo que imprime NAN cuando una ecuación tiene raíces complejas. Es normal porque en los reales no existe la raíz cuadrada de ningún número negativo. https://tio.run/##hZFhT4MwEIa/71dcMDOAVNzip@lM1PkvSMxRWtaktLMtyxLjXxeLCGNLcPfhkt69T/velZKS0qa5EorKumDwaF0h9O32aXYsVei2bWUmlIMKhQqjzxn44FKjg8NOW@HEXq/vEjgoVmJ3eBhp8raHbaJ94zftjL@Th8GmFI4Bk7BHqQ34V59XmQuiTmopKi@a8yC5xr/aNPkyQeYXydcJkkYjy2m6YRaN0VLqFpIIXJuqlnjUDCuBNYQkv7EfxoV5nJP7GGMaRWm4jPtBho11WvKf9sR/pt4vR3A2dKbeJBhma@mw0DD4ZHYFc56pTAXJ4P6MPSEH1x3pqb4y9mqYq40C/@VfTbOABZDlN@USS9sQWf0A